# Hard Drive Space Discrepancy?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

Anyone know why there would be a difference between the number shown at the bottom of the hard drive icon and the number of available space in '7.6 GB free of 272.42 GB' in the screenshot below?

[image: discrepancy]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe: "750 GB SATA Disk" has one partition called "Macintosh HD" of that smaller size?

Consult Disk Utility, "Partition" for that drive...

[image: partitioned]